# CAT6 RJ45 - Unidentified Network

Tags: ethernet, rj-45

I have tried 3 times now to attach new RJ45 connectors on each end of the CAT6 cable we have just run around my house and through the crawl space, (so really hoping it's not the wire because it is really difficult to access).

I have a tester, and the tester readout is fine no matter what end I do it on. All 8 lights run through on both sides in order. Before I was using powerline tech to get internet downstairs from the upstairs router and that worked fine, but I was barely getting 1/3 of the internet we were paying for.

But now I am plugging in this new cable I have done, I am getting "Identifying" for at least a minute or two, before it goes to "Unidentified Network: No Network Access."

Virgin Super Hub, going to Windows 7. Used less than 100m. Other Ethernet devices work fine. Which tells me it's the cable or connectors, but surely the tester would be showing something? The tester is saying it's fine?

Any ideas? Feel free to ask for any other information you may need.

3/10/15 15:10 EDIT: @dakre18, thanks for all of that. When I get home this evening I will try what you have said and get back to you.

Comment: The tester measures specifications as impedance and crosstalk or only wire connectivity?

Comment: @Mikelong1994 Welcome on SU. Now that you registered yourself you will be able to answer to the comment and accept the answer. Obviously for the question you will post as the _new yourself_  ...

Comment: I need to point out that although you used Category-6 cable, you probably cannot pass the Category-6 test with a real tester. You must use the correct cable (solid-core for the horizontal cable, and stranded for patch cords), the correct termination hardware (Category-6, and solid-core for the horizontal and stranded for the patch cords), and I have seen experienced installers struggle to get it to pass the tests. You probably wasted money on your choice of cable.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a laptop or another device you can test on the line, i would suggest trying that if you want to make sure the line is fine.  I would start with some basic steps, once connected there should be lights on both ends of the cable, then make sure your network adapter has the correct settings or is set to automatic (ip/dns settings).

If it's set to automatic, i would also suggest going into Command Prompt and run ipconfig /renew to see if it can update the network adapter.  Let's assume it still isn't working, then i would run ipconfig /all and double check if it grabbed any network information.  In some cases it could be something on the router/switch you use, but i would also suggest trying to ping your modem/router that acts as the DHCP server and any other computer ip addresses on the network.

That should give you an idea if it's getting anything, but if you know what IP you want, you can always try to set a static IP and see if that works.  If it does work, it's most likely something on the router that is causing the problem (not always, but generally).

It is possible you got a bad wire, but if that doesn't work we will need more information.  Like the information that comes up on an ipconfig /all (ip, subnet, gateway, dns), what the results of the pings were, what happens if you try setting a static IP versus a dynamic IP, what happened if you were able to connect multiple devices to the cable, and do you have any spare CAT6 or CAT5e cables?

That should help us or fix it for you, but one thing you should double check (so you are not wasting your time) is if your hardware is running on gigabit (computer and router/switches).  If you do not have gigabit hardware on both ends of a cable, a CAT6 is going to run on 100Mbps speed instead of 1000Mbps.  I assume you understand that, but it's good to double check you aren't wasting your time either.